# How to modify CacheInterceptor to Cache only last seconds

Tags: angular, typescript

I implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46531464/3963430) great example of a Cache Interceptor in Angular 5.2. So far it works very well. However, I would like to modify this cache so that only queries of the last 3 seconds are loaded from the cache, older ones should be re-requested. How can I achieve this?

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs/AsyncSubject';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class CacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private cache: { [name: string]: AsyncSubject<HttpEvent<any>> } = {};

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (request.method !== 'GET') {
            return next.handle(request);
        }
        const cachedResponse = this.cache[request.urlWithParams] || null;
        if (cachedResponse) {
            return cachedResponse
        }
        const subject = this.cache[request.urlWithParams] = new AsyncSubject<HttpEvent<any>>();
        next.handle(request).do(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                subject.next(event);
                subject.complete();
            }
        }).subscribe(); // must subscribe to actually kick off request!
        return subject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tryn this - just calculate timediff:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs/AsyncSubject';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class CacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private cache: { [name: string]: AsyncSubject<HttpEvent<any>> } = {};
    private prevTimeStamp: any = new Date();
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (request.method !== 'GET') {
            return next.handle(request);
        }
        const currentTimeStamp = new Date();
        const cachedResponse = this.cache[request.urlWithParams] || null;
         const diff = (currentTimeStamp - this.prevTimeStamp) / 1000;
        if (cachedResponse & (diff > 3)) {
            return cachedResponse
        }
        this.prevTimeStamp = currentTimeStamp;
        const subject = this.cache[request.urlWithParams] = new AsyncSubject<HttpEvent<any>>();
        next.handle(request).do(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                subject.next(event);
                subject.complete();
            }
        }).subscribe(); // must subscribe to actually kick off request!
        return subject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the solution approach with it I managed to develop my own solution. After 5 seconds cached objects are deleted and additionally after DELETE or POST, because I assume that something has changed. Maybe it's helpful to anyone. I'm not programming Angular for a long time, or if someone should discover an error in my approach, I'm grateful for feedback.

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs/AsyncSubject';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';


class CachedResponseObject {
    asyncSubject: AsyncSubject<HttpEvent<any>>
    timeStamp: Date = new Date()
}

@Injectable()
export class CacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private cache: { [name: string]: CachedResponseObject } = {};

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (request.method !== 'GET') {
            this.cache = {}; // Empty cache after POST or DELETE
            return next.handle(request);
        }

        // Delete all get-requests older than 5 seconds
        for (const key in this.cache) {

            if (this.cache[key].asyncSubject) {

                const currentTimeStamp: Date = new Date();

                const diff = (currentTimeStamp.getTime() - this.cache[key].timeStamp.getTime()) / 1000;

                if (diff > 5) {
                    delete (this.cache[key])
                }
            }

        }

        const cachedResponse = this.cache[request.urlWithParams] || null;

        if (cachedResponse) {
            return cachedResponse.asyncSubject// .delay(0);
        }

        const subject = this.cache[request.urlWithParams] = new CachedResponseObject()
        this.cache[request.urlWithParams].asyncSubject = new AsyncSubject<HttpEvent<any>>();
        this.cache[request.urlWithParams].timeStamp = new Date()

        next.handle(request).do(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                subject.asyncSubject.next(event);
                subject.asyncSubject.complete();
            }
        }).subscribe(); // must subscribe to actually kick off request!
        return subject.asyncSubject;
    }
}
```